# ActionCable + Nginx + Puma and java.io.EOFException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to connect to an ActionCable websocket and everything works fine running locally with just Puma and without nginx.

However, when I try to do the exact same thing on my staging environment, the connection is immediately closing after connecting.  I *am* able to get the downstream welcome messages and maybe a ping.

However, the connection abruptly closes without any of the onClose callbacks so my guess is nginx is not letting the connection persist.

Here is my sites nginx configuration.

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/my-app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=60;
  keepalive 60;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
#       websocket_pass websocket;

        root /home/deploy/my-app/current/public;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

        location @app {
          proxy_pass http://app;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }

        #location / {
        #        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        #        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #        proxy_redirect off;
        #        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        #        proxy_pass http://app;
        #}

        location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
          gzip_static on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /cable {
          proxy_pass http://app;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I also found this error in nginx error logs:

> 2019/02/11 21:08:35 [error] 10233#10233: *2 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying upgraded connection, client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET /cable/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deploy/wr-api/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/cable/", host: "x.x.x.x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time, we noticed that the staging environment cable.yml had this value for url:

```
url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
```

Removing that value and all other values except for `adapter: staging` fixed it for us.

New cable.yml staging config:

```
staging:
  adapter: redis
```

Working!